# How to include and use ZXing Library in Android with eclipse?

Tags: android

I am new to the concept of ZXing,so i want to know the step by step process to use the ZXing in android and i am using elicpse as IDE.Any one knows about it please help me.

Comment: I think you need a more specific question than this. What specifically is your question? Ask at http://groups.google.com/group/zxing/

Comment: Check my detailed answer: [How to use ZXing in Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30572168/165071)

Comment: Please check my answer :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application/34941618#34941618

Answer (score 7):

As advised by the moderator, I am posting what did to import zxing into my android app, on this post. Seems like many people refer to this post to get an answer for zxing.

The zxing guys have made it easier to create a android project with 1.7. Its not as painful as it used to be. This is a quick blog for anyone who would like to create a zxing project for android quickly.

- Checkout the zxing sources from zxing.org
- Create a Android project on your eclipse
- Delete main.xml
- Right click on “src” directory and hit import. Browse to the following directories in the order mentioned. As you add them for
  import one by one, ensure that you have the src directory in the edit
  field of the import wizard. And that you select only the “com”
  directory on the left directory tree. Do not select src.

  - core
  - android-integration
  - android
  - Ensure that your android sdk version is 9, anything lesser and androidmanifest.xml will cry.
  - Strings.xml in one of the languages will crib, just put a / before the ‘ character

For the benefit of people,

- I have a android hello world integrated with zxing 1.7 http://www.4shared.com/file/bFx8Y5Ys/zXingJune2010.html
- Another blog that has interesting direction for integrating zxing
  http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Comment: Damian Flannery's Blog was helpful and the only proper way to integrate it. Thanks.