# How to import and use zxing libraries?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I really don't know how to use zxing libraries.

I downloaded the zxing-1.7.zip and zxing-2.zip and I configured the path of the Android project to include them as libraries. I'm trying to use i.e: `IntentIntegrator` but it is not available. Also I tried to use `import zxing` but it gives me error.

My question is: how to import the zxing-1.7.zip and zxing-2.zip the .jave file?

Comment: zxing-1.7.zip will be having  a zxing-1.7.jar file...

then rt clk on the project then go to properties....
PROPERTIES>JAVA BUILD PATH>ADD JAR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As advised by the moderator, I am posting what did to import zxing into my android app, on this post. Seems like many people refer to this post to get an answer for zxing.

The zxing guys have made it easier to create a android project with 1.7. Its not as painful as it used to be. This is a quick blog for anyone who would like to create a zxing project for android quickly.

- Checkout the zxing sources from zxing.org
- Create a Android project on your eclipse
- Delete main.xml
- Right click on “src” directory and hit import. Browse to the following directories in the order mentioned. As you add them for
  import one by one, ensure that you have the src directory in the edit
  field of the import wizard. And that you select only the “com”
  directory on the left directory tree. Do not select src.

  - core
  - android-integration
  - android
  - Ensure that your android sdk version is 9, anything lesser and androidmanifest.xml will cry.
  - Strings.xml in one of the languages will crib, just put a / before the ‘ character

For the benefit of people,

- I have a android hello world integrated with zxing 1.7 http://www.4shared.com/file/bFx8Y5Ys/zXingJune2010.html
- Another blog that has interesting direction for integrating zxing
  http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

The above answer is Refered from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108983/1602230

Comment: thanks, but after downloading your source code i found many packages and i dont know which one contains hello world...please tell me which one

Comment: Please do not encourage people to copy and paste the whole project. It is not intended to be used this way, causes problems for us, and is not even OK. Either integrate by Intent, or start from your own app, and integrate parts you need. Do not clone our app. (Also, 1.7 is very old.)