# Unable to compare int variable in Zxing qr scanner onActivityResult

Tags: android, fragment, zxing

I am actually trying to intent my fragment to Zxing qr scanner when the button is clicked.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");// for Qr code, its
                                                            // "QR_CODE_MODE"
                                                            // instead of
                                                            // "PRODUCT_MODE"
            intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);// this stops saving ur
                                                    // barcode in barcode
                                                    // scanner app's history
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The problem i am facing is that in the codes below, i am unable to get my resultCode to compare to RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED. I managed to do this in an activity just fine but when i wanted to implement in my fragment class i am unable to do so.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("onActivityResult", "Started");
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); 

                TextView txt_qrCode = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_helloWorld);
//              txt_qrCode.setText(contents);
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276635/how-to-include-and-use-zxing-library-in-android-with-eclipse/9108983#9108983

Comment: I am actually going to intent to zxing native app on the market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question.

int android.app.Activity.RESULT_CANCELED = 0 [0x0]

Because the RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED is actually relying on activity and in my fragment class there is no activity. I simply put

```
if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK)
.
.
```

instead of

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
.
.
```

This would allow me to get the parent activity that inflates the fragment.

Comment: You should just use `Activity.RESULT_OK` -- it's a static constant.